# Fedora: Touchscreen works in live mode, but not after install

Tags: linux, fedora, touch-screen

Recently I've been playing with Linux on Thinkpad 10 2nd gen tablet. Currently Fedora 24 is running on it. When I boot from USB stick (live mode), touchscreen works and is detected as Wacom 5020 HID, but after installing it touchscreen doesn't work, and is not detected by xinput.

Here is some info I got from both live image, and installed OS (@live and @install respectively):

**NOTE:** since `lspci` and `lsusb` are identical I've omitted them to avoid 30 000 char limit.

**lsmod**

```
[user@live ~]$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
acpi_pad               36864  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
auth_rpcgss            61440  1 nfsd
bluetooth             491520  11 bnep,btbcm,btqca,hci_uart,btintel
bnep                   20480  2
brcmfmac              249856  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
bridge                126976  1 ebtable_broute
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
cfg80211              565248  1 brcmfmac
coretemp               16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
drm                   335872  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
drm_kms_helper        131072  1 i915
ebtable_broute         16384  1
ebtable_filter         16384  1
ebtable_nat            16384  1
ebtables               32768  3 ebtable_broute,ebtable_nat,ebtable_filter
fat                    65536  1 vfat
fjes                   28672  0
fuse                   98304  3
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
hci_uart               77824  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
i915                 1220608  15
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
intel_hid              16384  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
ip6_tables             28672  5 ip6table_filter,ip6table_mangle,ip6table_security,ip6table_nat,ip6table_raw
ip6t_REJECT            16384  2
ip6t_rpfilter          16384  1
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_nat           16384  1
ip6table_raw           16384  1
ip6table_security      16384  1
ip_set                 36864  0
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
iptable_raw            16384  1
iptable_security       16384  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
joydev                 20480  0
kvm                   552960  1 kvm_intel
kvm_intel             184320  0
llc                    16384  2 stp,bridge
lockd                  90112  1 nfsd
loop                   28672  6
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_txe
mei_txe                20480  0
mmc_block              36864  3
mmc_core              126976  4 mmc_block,sdhci,brcmfmac,sdhci_acpi
nf_conntrack          106496  8 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv6,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack_broadcast    16384  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  11
nf_conntrack_ipv6      20480  12
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    16384  0
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6         36864  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_nat                 24576  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv6
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat_ipv6            16384  1 ip6table_nat
nf_reject_ipv6         16384  1 ip6t_REJECT
nfnetlink              16384  1 ip_set
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
nfsd                  323584  1
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
rfkill                 24576  7 cfg80211,bluetooth
scsi_dh_alua           16384  0
scsi_dh_emc            16384  0
scsi_dh_rdac           16384  0
scsi_transport_iscsi    94208  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
snd                    77824  7 snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0
snd_intel_sst_core     73728  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_pcm               114688  3 snd_soc_core,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq                69632  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_soc_core          204800  1 snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform    90112  1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
soc_button_array       16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sparse_keymap          16384  1 intel_hid
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
squashfs               49152  1
stp                    16384  1 bridge
sunrpc                319488  7 nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
tpm                    40960  2 tpm_crb,tpm_tis
tpm_crb                16384  0
tpm_tis                20480  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            65536  2 uas
vfat                   20480  1
video                  40960  1 i915
wacom                  90112  0
wmi                    20480  0
xt_conntrack           16384  21
```

Note that they're in ascending mode for easier comparison, and that `wacom` module is loaded on both.

```
[user@install ~]$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
acpi_pad               36864  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
auth_rpcgss            61440  1 nfsd
bluetooth             491520  11 bnep,btbcm,btqca,hci_uart,btintel
bnep                   20480  2
brcmfmac              249856  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
bridge                126976  1 ebtable_broute
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
cfg80211              565248  1 brcmfmac
coretemp               16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
drm                   335872  9 i915,drm_kms_helper
drm_kms_helper        131072  1 i915
ebtable_broute         16384  1
ebtable_filter         16384  1
ebtable_nat            16384  1
ebtables               32768  3 ebtable_broute,ebtable_nat,ebtable_filter
fat                    65536  1 vfat
fjes                   28672  0
fuse                   98304  4
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
hci_uart               77824  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
i915                 1220608  13
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
intel_hid              16384  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
ip6_tables             28672  5 ip6table_filter,ip6table_mangle,ip6table_security,ip6table_nat,ip6table_raw
ip6t_REJECT            16384  2
ip6t_rpfilter          16384  1
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_nat           16384  1
ip6table_raw           16384  1
ip6table_security      16384  1
ip_set                 36864  0
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
iptable_raw            16384  1
iptable_security       16384  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
joydev                 20480  0
kvm                   552960  1 kvm_intel
kvm_intel             184320  0
llc                    16384  2 stp,bridge
lockd                  90112  1 nfsd
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_txe
mei_txe                20480  0
mmc_block              36864  4
mmc_core              126976  4 mmc_block,sdhci,brcmfmac,sdhci_acpi
nf_conntrack          106496  8 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv6,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack_broadcast    16384  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  11
nf_conntrack_ipv6      20480  12
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    16384  0
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6         36864  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_nat                 24576  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv6
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat_ipv6            16384  1 ip6table_nat
nf_reject_ipv6         16384  1 ip6t_REJECT
nfnetlink              16384  1 ip_set
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
nfsd                  323584  1
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
rfkill                 24576  7 cfg80211,bluetooth
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
snd                    77824  7 snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0
snd_intel_sst_core     73728  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_pcm               114688  3 snd_soc_core,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq                69632  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_soc_core          204800  1 snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform    90112  1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
soc_button_array       16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sparse_keymap          16384  1 intel_hid
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
sunrpc                319488  7 nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
tpm                    40960  2 tpm_crb,tpm_tis
tpm_crb                16384  0
tpm_tis                20480  0
vfat                   20480  1
video                  40960  1 i915
wacom                  90112  0
wmi                    20480  0
xt_conntrack           16384  21
```

**xinput --list**

```
[user@live ~]$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5020 Pen stylus                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5020 Finger                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5020 Pen eraser                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Installed OS doesn't show Wacom HID 5020:

```
[user@install ~]$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

even though they're listed in `/proc/bus/input/devices`

**cat /proc/bus/input/devices**

```
[user@live ~]$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c31c Version=0110
N: Name="Logitech USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0002/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c31c Version=0110
N: Name="Logitech USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0003/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=2010000 397ad801d001 1e000000000000 0
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1c4f Product=0003 Version=0110
N: Name="SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3:1.0/0003:1C4F:0003.0004/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID events"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/INT33D5:00/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 rfkill 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000300000000 5000004000 1e294000000020 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=5020 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 5020 Pen"
P: Phys=i2c-WCOM5020:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-5/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0005/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1c03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000003
B: MSC=1

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=5020 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 5020 Finger"
P: Phys=i2c-WCOM5020:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-5/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0005/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event7 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0
```

And for the installed OS:

```
[user@install ~]$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID events"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/INT33D5:00/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 rfkill 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000300000000 5000004000 1e294000000020 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=5020 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 5020 Pen"
P: Phys=i2c-WCOM5020:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-12/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0005/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1c03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000003
B: MSC=1

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=5020 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 5020 Finger"
P: Phys=i2c-WCOM5020:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-12/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0005/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event8 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c31c Version=0110
N: Name="Logitech USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.000C/input/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c31c Version=0110
N: Name="Logitech USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.000D/input/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=2010000 397ad801d001 1e000000000000 0
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1c4f Product=0003 Version=0110
N: Name="SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3:1.0/0003:1C4F:0003.000E/input/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10
```

Last but not least

**dmesg**

[user@live dmesg](http://pastebin.com/XEDyVur0)

[user@install dmesg](http://pastebin.com/EtJXTNx6)

I don't expect anyone to sip through all of those messages so here are messages related to wacom:

**dmesg | grep -i wacom**

```
[user@live ~]$ dmesg | grep -i wacom
[   21.392115] input: Wacom HID 5020 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-5/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0004/input/input7
[   21.393193] input: Wacom HID 5020 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-5/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0004/input/input8
[   21.394768] wacom 0018:056A:5020.0004: hidraw3: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [WCOM5020:00 056A:5020] on i2c-WCOM5020:00
[   21.858532] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[   21.861114] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[   21.864117] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[   21.867107] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[   21.869984] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[   21.872228] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[   21.873119] Modules linked in: intel_rapl coretemp snd_intel_sst_acpi kvm_intel snd_intel_sst_core kvm wacom snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match irqbypass brcmfmac snd_soc_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support snd_compress joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine brcmutil ac97_bus cfg80211 snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm i915 hci_uart snd_timer btbcm btqca snd btintel soundcore bluetooth wmi i2c_algo_bit intel_hid drm_kms_helper rfkill i2c_designware_platform sparse_keymap video i2c_designware_core drm mei_txe soc_button_array tpm_crb mei shpchp lpc_ich processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis acpi_pad tpm spi_pxa2xx_platform nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace vfat fat squashfs mmc_block uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
```

And on installed OS:

```
[user@install ~]$ dmesg | grep -i wacom
[    9.179647] wacom 0018:056A:5020.0005: wacom_get_report: ran out of retries (last error = -121)
[    9.179651] wacom 0018:056A:5020.0005: wacom_feature_mapping: could not get HID_DG_CONTACTMAX, defaulting to 16
[    9.179804] input: Wacom HID 5020 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-12/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0005/input/input8
[    9.182614] input: Wacom HID 5020 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-12/i2c-WCOM5020:00/0018:056A:5020.0005/input/input9
[    9.185121] wacom 0018:056A:5020.0005: hidraw3: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [WCOM5020:00 056A:5020] on i2c-WCOM5020:00
[    9.193206] wacom 0018:056A:5020.0005: wacom_set_report: ran out of retries (last error = -121)
```

As you can see, there are some errors related to wacom on installed OS, but I don't know why, and how to fix them. I've tried following touchscreen related wiki on ubuntu page but no dice. There are 32 ttyS, but only ttyS0, ttyS4, and ttyS5 don't exit `screen`, and none of those three give me any input while touching the screen.

Has anyone here came across this or similar problem? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Please note that info displayed above didn't come from single boot in live mode or single boot in installed OS. I've rebooted from one mode to another and collected info as I needed it.

**EDIT #1:** After spending some time in log viewer I've stumbled upon log messages about `udev` and `systemd-logind` registering input devices. As you can see, in live mode everything registers just fine, but on an installed OS these errors are logged:

```
systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/input/event7: Invalid argument
xf86OpenSerial: Cannot open device /dev/input/event7
Wacom HID 5020 Pen: Error opening /dev/input/event7 (Permission denied)
```

Log messages are in descending order (GNOMEs log viewer shows them and saves them as such):

**user@install**

```
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (EE) PreInit returned 8 for "Wacom HID 5020 Pen"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (EE) Wacom HID 5020 Pen: Error opening /dev/input/event7 (Permission denied)
13:13:21 gdm-x-session:     Permission denied.
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (EE) xf86OpenSerial: Cannot open device /dev/input/event7
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (**) Wacom HID 5020 Pen: always reports core events
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom HID 5020 Pen'
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/input/event7: Invalid argument
13:13:21 gdm-x-session:     usb:17ef:6004 {omitted}
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) wacom: Driver for Wacom graphics tablets: PenPartner, Graphire,
13:13:21 gdm-x-session:     ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
13:13:21 gdm-x-session:     Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
13:13:21 gdm-x-session:     compiled for 1.18.0, module version = 0.32.0
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) Module wacom: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) LoadModule: "wacom"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (**) Wacom HID 5020 Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom class"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (**) Wacom HID 5020 Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB device class"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (**) Wacom HID 5020 Pen: Applying InputClass "evdev tablet catchall"
13:13:21 gdm-x-session: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom HID 5020 Pen (/dev/input/event7)
```